# Ap Computer Science Java Interfaces and Compare method dilemma

Tags: java, oop, interface, constructor, compare

I'm supposed to  write a Cruiser class which implements the Locatable interface. Cruiser will have x, y, and speed properties. x, y, and speed are integer numbers. You must provide 3 constructors for class Cruiser. Class Cruiser must implement the Locatable interface.

One constructor must be a default. One constructor must be an x and y only constructor. One constructor must be an x, y, and speed constructor. You must provide an equals method. The equals() method should compare the properties of two Cruiser Objects. You must provide a toString() method. The toString() should return the x, y, and speed of the Cruiser.

When i compile this it says "class Cruiser is public, should be declared in Cruiser.java"

When i do this my IDE says ";" as expected after public boolean equals. but that doesn't make sense why you would need a semicolon in a method.

this is what i have so far

```
 public interface Locatable
 {
 public int getxPos();
 public int getyPos();
 }

 public class Cruiser implements Locatable
 {
 private int xPos, yPos, speed;
 public Cruiser()
 {
 xPos=yPos=speed=0;
 }

 public Cruiser(int x,int y)
 {
 xPos=x;
 yPos=y;
 speed=0;
 }

 public Cruiser(int x, int y, int spd)
 {
 xPos=x;
 yPos=y;
 speed=spd;
 }

 public int getxPos()
 {
 return xPos;
 }

 public int getyPos()
 {
 return yPos;
 }

 public int getSpeed()
 {
 return speed;
 }

 public void compare(Cruiser A, Cruiser B)
 {
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) 
 {
 if (obj instanceof Cruiser) {
    Cruiser cruiserToCompareTo = (Cruiser)obj;

    if(xPos == cruiserToCompareTo.getXpos() &&
            yPos == cruiserToCompareTo.getYpos() &&
            speed == cruiserToCompareTo.getSpeed())
        return true;            
}
return false;
}
public String toString()
{
String properties = "X position:"+ xPos+ ", Y position:"+yPos+ ",Speed:"+speed;
return properties;
}
} 
}
```

Comment: Could you take the time to properly align your code? This makes it easier for us to read. In an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans you can do this in a few clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what it means that equals should compare the fields/properties.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Point) {
        Point pt = (Point)obj;
        return (x == pt.x) && (y == pt.y);
    }
    return super.equals(obj);
}
```

This example is taken from `java.awt.Point`
which is one of the Java's built-in classes.
So `Point` has 2 properties `x` and `y`, and
in its equals method it is comparing them.

See also:

[java.awt.Point.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: How do i incorporate your suggestion into my code? Also do you know how to implement an interface?

Comment: 1) Incorporate it literally or almost literally (just think about the analogy to your case). 2) Yes, I know.

Comment: is this the correct way to implement an interface                   public interface Locatable
{
    public int getxPos();
    public int getyPos();
}
public class Cruiser implements Locatable
{

Comment: Yes. Seems right to me. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html

Comment: I just updated my code can you check it and help me? It's not running and When i compile this it says "class Cruiser is public, should be declared in Cruiser.java"

however when i create a new class called Cruiser.java and copy the code and paste it in there it says "class Locatable is public, should be declared in Locatable.java". I don't know what to do anymore please help!

Comment: Declare them in two separate files as the compiler is trying to tell you. Or just remove the `public` modifier from Locatable and keep the name of the file as Cruiser.java.

Comment: when i remove the public modifier it says that "public cruiser()" is an invalid method declaration and that it needs a return type. however public cruiser() is my default constructor and i have to have that.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Cruiser A with properties x,y,speed and you have Cruiser B with x,y,speed. Equals shall return true, if A.x == B.x, A.y == B.y, A.speed == B.speed all are true. Cruiser A and Cruiser B are therefor equal, when all parameters are equal.

Edit: Following Code should be entered into Cruiser-Class

```
public int getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Cruiser) {
        Cruiser cruiserToCompareTo = (Cruiser)obj;

        if(xPos == cruiserToCompareTo.getXpos() &&
                yPos == cruiserToCompareTo.getYpos() &&
                speed == cruiserToCompareTo.getSpeed())
            return true;            
    }
    return false;
}
```

And please: Format you code better and furthermore name methods in Cruiser-Class same way as in the interface.

Edit 2: Regarding your second problem:
You need to have to separate files, Cruiser.java and Locatable.java. Code runs well here

Comment: How would i write that? would i have to change/remove my compare method?

Comment: What would i write in each file? or would i just have two of the same file just with different names?

Comment: I did what you said however the Cruiser.java file won't run because it says i need a semi colon in public Cruiser(). However, public Cruiser() is a default constructor so why on earth would it need a semi colon?